# Is it possible to resolve a domain name from the browser history?

Tags: browser, dns, logging

If an entry is removed from the DNS. Is it possible to retrieve its IP from a browser history? Is it possible to extract from the history all the different addresses I've been redirected to every time I visit "www.google.com"?

Comment: no not under normal circumstances. a browser could be programmed to cache IPs, but most are not, because it clashes with the purpose of DNS. the browser instead relies on the facilities of the hosts to perform the lookup. that way if the DNS entry changes for a host, all the client links/bookmarks to it would behave unpredictably at best and it would enable a rather dangerous kind of phishing deployment. if the host hasn't rebooted, and your DNS cache hasn't been flushed or invalidated, you might be able to get the IP there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This should be an answer, not a comment :)